# Flume agent - can I specify compression like gzip or bz2?

Tags: hadoop, agent, cloudera, flume

Is it possible to specify a compression option on a Flume agent so that the data is transferred to the collector in a compressed format?  I know there are compression options on the collector level, but it would be also extremely useful to be able to transfer compressed data from the agent, too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Flume has the `gzip` and `gunzip` sink decorators that you can use. Put the `gzip` decorator on your agent sink and the `gunzip` decorator on your collector sink, and transferring compressed data between the agent and collector should Just Work.

Comment: Is it possible to zip the data on the agent and let it flow zipped through the collector into HDFS without unzipping / zipping it again?